# Requiring Node.js/Express.js Middleware has no Method '...'

Tags: node.js, methods, express, middleware

I have an issue when requiring Express.js middleware; I have the code in `app.'s`:

```
...
var middlewares = require('./middlewares');
...
routes = require('./routes')(app, config, crypto, middlewares, models, oauth2);
...
```

This requires `./middlewares/index.js`:

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var middlewares = function (app, config, models, oauth2) {
  var that = {};

  that.touch = require('./touch.js')(app, config, models, oauth2);

  return that;
};

module.exports = middlewares;
```

Which in turn (the above is simplified but would contain require other middleware too) requires `./middlewares/touch.js`:

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node: true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var touch = function (app, config, models, oauth2) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Touch');

    next();
  };
};

module.exports = touch;
```

And call it from `./routes/index.js`:

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var routes = function (app, config, crypto, middlewares, models, oauth2) {
  var that = {};

  app.get(
    '/',
    middlewares.touch(app, config, models, oauth2),
    function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello world!');
    }
  );

  that.auth = require('./auth')(app, config, crypto, models, oauth2);

  return that;
};

module.exports = routes;
```

Though when I do this I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object function (app, config, models, oauth2) {
  var that = {};

  that.touch = require('./touch.js')(app, config, models, oauth2);

  return that;
} has no method 'touch'
```

When I require `./middlewares/touch.js` from `app.js` like:

```
...
var touch = require('./middlewares/touch.js');
...
routes = require('./routes')(app, config, crypto, touch, models, oauth2);
...
```

And in `./routes/index.js` I call it like:

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var routes = function (app, config, crypto, touch, models, oauth2) {
  var that = {};

  app.get(
    '/',
    touch(app, config, models, oauth2),
    function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello world!');
    }
  );

  that.auth = require('./auth')(app, config, crypto, models, oauth2);

  return that;
};

module.exports = routes;
```

I am error free! Must be the way I am referencing it through `./middlewares/index.js` but I can for the life of me work it out?

Any ideas Stack Overflow?

EDIT:

OK, so then the question remains;

- I want to `require` `./middlewares/index.js` from inside `app.js`
- `./middlewares/index.js` requires all my middlewares e.g. `./touch.js`
- I only need to pass the `middlewares` object into other modules to access its methods e.g. `middlewares` can be passed into my `routes` module and I can reference the touch middleware like `middlewares.touch()`

Very simply; I wish to `require` all my middlewares and pass them into the routes module like:

```
...
var middlewares = require('./middlewares');
...
routes = require('./routes')(app, middlewares);
...
```

And use my middlewares in a route like:

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var routes = function (app, middlewares) {
  var that = {};

  app.get(
    '/',
    middlewares.touch,
    function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello world!');
    }
  );

  that.auth = require('./auth')(app);

  return that;
};

module.exports = routes;
```

How should I go about that? Look at the top of this question to see how I'm trying (and failing) to do it now, thanks everyone for their help!

In addition, should modules `return` something, e.g.; the `routes` module doesn't really need to return anything, or *does/should* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `middlewares` returns a function that when executed returns an object instead of just an object like you are using it in `./routes/index.js`.

You can do 1 of 2 things.

1) Change `./middlewares/index.js` to set `module.exports` to an object literal.

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var middlewares = {

  touch : require('./touch.js')(app, config, models, oauth2)

};

module.exports = middlewares;
```

***-- OR --***

2) Change `./routes/index.js` to run `middlewares` before calling touch.

```
/*jslint es5: true, indent: 2, node:true, nomen: true, maxlen: 80, vars: true*/

'use strict';

var routes = function (app, config, crypto, middlewares, models, oauth2) {
  var that = {};

  app.get(
    '/',
    middlewares().touch(app, config, models, oauth2),
    function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello world!');
    }
  );

  that.auth = require('./auth')(app, config, crypto, models, oauth2);

  return that;
};

module.exports = routes;
```

I am partial to option 1 but it depends on if you need to do something in `./middlewares/index.js` before building up the return object.

Based on the code you have it looks like option 1 suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Frist off:
both awnsers are correct

the middlewares/index.js returns a function in its exports

and inside the routes.js you try to use the member touch of that function, which doenst exist

Secondly:

It looks like you could us some help structuring your app, which youve done very thoroughly but doing it this way makes the components very dependant on eachother/the app

you inject the dependancies (app, config, crypto, middlewares, models, oauth2, ... etc)
into each module instead of having them get their own

in your app.js you probably do something like

```
var OAuth2Lib = require('some/path/oauth2');
var oauth2 = new OAuth2Lib(some.config);
```

and repeat for all other [crypto, cnfig, models,...]
once thats done you run the

```
routes = require('./routes')(app, config, crypto, middlewares, models, oauth2);
```

If you put the construction code to make the oahth2 into a new module you can require that whenever you need it (put it in `lib/oauth2.js`):

```
var OAuth2Lib = require('some/path/oauth2');
var oauth2 = new OAuth2Lib(some.config);
module.exports = oauth2;
```

to use that inside: `./middlewares/touch.js`:

```
var oauth2 = require('../lib/oauth2');
var config = require('../config/config');
var models = require('../lib/models');

var touch = function (app) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Touch');

    next();
  };
};

module.exports = touch;
```

now there is only the app dependancy left (if you need that at all)
be carefull with middleware order, especially things like cookieParse, bodyParser (express) should be app.use'd before your own custom middlewares

Answer (score 1):

Every function is an object.

Functional object `middlewares` has no method `touch`, and this is true.  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code, but `touch` method is in what the function *returns*, and not a member of the function itself.

This would work, in terms of syntax: `middlwares().touch`, or direct member assignment
`middlwares.touch = ...`, and then you can access it, although I highly doubt if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes; but the function returned by `./middlewares/touch.js` is assigned to `middlewares.touch` in the first examples, is it not? Albeit though `./middlewares/index.js`though I would prefer it that way, as I would like all middlewares avaliable from one object e.g. `middlewares.touch`, `middlewares.otherFunc`etc. I think it must be something to do with the `./middlewares/index.js` proxy?

Comment: Thanks, I've added to my question then; could you take a look and suggest how I should be doing this then, I obviously don't understand your first answer unfortunately. Could you make it more comprehensive? Thanks for your help so far!